# Mostrar valores de procedimiento almacenado como json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema, estoy creando dos funciones para mostrar consultas en formato json.
Este es mi código:

```
<?php
include'db.php';
class Descuento extends Database{
    public function listar_producto(){
        $sql = "CALL sp_mostrar_producto";
        $array = array();
        $query = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $array[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    public function listar_categoria(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alm_categoria ";
        $array = array();
        $query = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $array[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($array);
    }

}

$desc = new Descuento();
if(isset($_GET["show"])){
    $respuesta = $_GET["show"];
    if($respuesta == 1){
        $desc->listar_producto();
    }elseif($respuesta == 2){
        $desc->listar_categoria();
    }

}

?>
```

El problema es que cuando tengo que mostrar **listar_producto()**, no muestra, mientras que **listar_categoria()** si lo hace. Añado también, que cuando uso la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM glb_producto
```

en listar_producto(), si funciona
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por que no es una select, tienes que diseñar el procedimiento en el SQL de modo que puedas linekear las variables.

Te recomiendo que uses PDO en vez de mysqli si necesitas llamar a procedimientos y funciones personalizadas (en mysqli es php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php, pero no tengo claro se si te funcionará correctamente).

Con PDO tienes los ejemplos aquí (http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements):

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_takes_string_returns_string(?)");
$value = 'hello';
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $value\n";
```

Te pongo un ejemplo de como hacerlo con Oracle (fuente: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html):

```
<?php
// etc.

$sql = 'BEGIN sayHello(:name, :message); END;';

You then bind the parameters to PHP variables with calls to oci_bind_by_name() .

If the sayHello procedure was defined by the following DDL statement:

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
        sayHello (name IN VARCHAR2, greeting OUT VARCHAR2) 
    AS
        BEGIN
            greeting := 'Hello ' || name;
        END;
/

Note that you can run the above statement using the SQL*Plus command line. Save the statement to a file (SAYHELLO.SQL). Next, login with SQL*Plus:

$ sqlplus username@SID

Then create the procedure using the START command:

SQL> START /home/username/SAYHELLO.SQL

The following PHP script calls the procedure:

<?php
$conn = oci_connect('SCOTT','TIGER') or die;


$sql = 'BEGIN sayHello(:name, :message); END;';

$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql);

//  Bind the input parameter
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':name',$name,32);

// Bind the output parameter
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':message',$message,32);

// Assign a value to the input 
$name = 'Harry';

oci_execute($stmt);

// $message is now populated with the output value
print "$message\n";
```